# Algorithm for finding the set of minimum, bounding $n$-spheres that covers a finite set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

Let $P$ be a non-empty, finite set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I want to know if there is an algorithm that can find the most optimal set of $n$-spheres $S$ that follows these properties:

- Each $n$-sphere in $S$ overlaps with at least one of the other $n$-spheres in $S$,
- For all $p \in P$, there exists $s \in S$ with center point $c_s$ and radius $r_s$ such that $\text{distance}(c_s, p) \leq r_s$, where $\text{distance}(x, y)$ is the Euclidean distance between two points of the same dimension,

$S$ is optimal if the volume occupied by the union of all the $n$-spheres in $S$ is minimum and $1 \leq |S| < |P|$. If $S$ has no optimal solution, at the very least a solution that approximates it.

For example, if $n = 2$ the following image shows how a set of circles could possibly cover a set of two-dimensional points:

[image: Set of circles cover a set of 2d points.]

**Side Note:** If we restrict $|S| = 1$ and $n = 2$, it becomes the [Smallest-circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem). In general, if $|S| = 1$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, it becomes the [Minimal bounding sphere problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_sphere). Both are solvable in worse case linear time.

---